# How can I formulate a "choose 1 from N" problem into a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

Lets say I have a set of N items, and I want to choose the best one.

Each item is represented using 6 feature.

I could fix N but it would be nice if it can vary.

The "best choice" might depends on what other item is present in the set

Is there a way to formulate it?

Comment: welcome to CV. your question is not clear to me. how do you define "best", how features will be used?

Comment: I have bunch of labeled data which label the "best" item out of a set

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by best you mean the most likely, you can think of your problem as a classification problem, if N is the number of categories. About fitting the model with an unknown number of classes, I afraid I don't know any methods. However, you could construct your fitting method taking this into account.

Incremental fitting is possible, and is implemented by some libraries. You could keep training the model on regular data, and when you see a new class, re instantiate the model with the whole data and resume the partial fitting process with the new number of classes.

Python's `sklearn` [module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html) implements some partial fitting models, such as;

- naive_bayes.MultinomialNB
- naive_bayes.BernoulliNB
- linear_model.Perceptron
- linear_model.SGDClassifier
- linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier

At least this is how I would progress If I was not sure how many classes there would be at my classification problem.

Comment: The right choice depends on what is present in the set, I dont think simple classification would work

Comment: Present in the set of what?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask the question good enough. Let say I have a set of fruit, which I want to pick one from. I would pick apple if there is a banana, but if there is an apple and a orange, I would pick the orange. so on and so forth. The right choice depends on what other fruit is present on the table.

Comment: And how is the best fruit, given the set of fruits on the table, defined?

Comment: The rule of choosing the best fruit is what I what the model to derive. I have training sample of many set of fruit with the "best fruit" labeled.